# Neatly use bias trick in deep learning

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I'm working on a simple example of how to use the bias trick in the forward pass of a neural network. I guess my code is correct so far, but is it really necessary to add an array of "1" manually to each activation, or is there a simpler way to do it?

```
import numpy as np

def f(z):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))

###Define the network, use bias trick###
x=np.random.rand(4,1)
x=np.concatenate((x,np.array([[1]])))
W1=np.random.rand(3,4+1)
W2=np.random.rand(3,3+1)
W3=np.random.rand(2,3+1)

###Do forward pass###
z1=W1@x
a1=f(z1)
a1=np.concatenate((a1,np.array([[1]])))
z2=W2@a1
a2=f(z2)
a2=np.concatenate((a2,np.array([[1]])))
z3=W3@a2
yhat=f(z3)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about rewriting `f` to account for that, something as the following will do the trick:

```py
import numpy as np

def f(z, final_activation=False):

    a = 1/(1+np.exp(-z))
    return a if final_activation else np.r_[a, [[1]]] 

###Define the network, use bias trick###
x=np.random.rand(4,1)
x=np.concatenate((x,np.array([[1]])))
W1=np.random.rand(3,4+1)
W2=np.random.rand(3,3+1)
W3=np.random.rand(2,3+1)

###Do forward pass###
z1=W1@x
a1=f(z1)

z2=W2@a1
a2=f(z2)

z3=W3@a2
yhat=f(z3, True)
```